# My app is closing after i pic the date , can anyone help me , i have attatched the code

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, datepickerdialog

This is my code and it crashes after i select the date in date picker dialog

```
bdaybutton.setOnClickListener { view -\\\>

    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val abc = DatePickerDialog(  this , DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
    { view , year, month, day -\\\>

        flag2 = true
        year2 = year
        val selecteddate = "${day/month+1/year}"
        bdaydatetext.text = "${day/month+1/year}"
        val sdf = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
        val date2 = sdf.parse(selecteddate)
        time2 = date2.time.toInt()

    }, cyear, cmonth, cday)

    abc.show()
```

]

}[image]

The error in the imge appears when after selecting the date

Comment: unparseable date: "12" makes sense to me, doesn't it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> "${day/month+1/year}"
> ```

This computes the expression inside the `{}` and converts it to a string. Looks like you wanted something like

```
"${day}/${month+1}/${year}"
```

instead there.

Better yet, skip the string conversion step altogether and use something like Java 8 `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` directly instead.